# ad-lds and active-directory-lds tag merge request

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, retag-request, merge

Can someone please merge the [ad-lds](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ad-lds) and [active-directory-lds](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/active-directory-lds) tags please?

[ad-lds](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ad-lds) is the preferred tag to remain.

Answer (score 1):

This is now complete.

(we like to have answers on these so they don't show up as no answers..)

Comment: Better have an upvote so community doesn't keep poking them then.